Why am I having an issue with restoring cursor position when using Basta on macOS terminal?
I'm debugging a display glitch that occurs in the operation of Basta (Bash Status Line) on macOS.
Whenever the interrupt arrives to refresh the clock display, the cursor column position does not restore, only the row position. I.e. the cursor jumps to the leftmost column. That happens every 15 seconds, which is the update interval.
When the user continues typing, everything is fine; the cursor jumps back into the Bash command line at the correct spot.
Basta uses the ESC 7 and ESC 8 sequences to save and restore the cursor position around the update. This works on numerous terminals, Gnome Terminal, PuTTY, Xterm, and others.
Unfortunately, the problem does not reproduce in a small test case such as this:
esc=$(printf "\033")
printf "cursor should be here: ${esc}7 <---\r${esc}8"
read

In this test case, we print the <--- arrow after the cursor position and then navigate to the start of the line with a carriage return. Lo and behold, the cursor is restored to the expected position just after the here:  and the scripts wait for return to be pressed:
Cursor should be here: █<---

So that works fine. Is there known some bug in Terminal around this, and if so, where is it documented, and what are the conditions under which it happens and repro steps?
New info: Using the script utility, I captured what is going to the terminal. If I just let it sit there, then what happens every 15 seconds is this:
...^[8^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[7...

The ^[8 is the epilogue of the previous update, issued by the alarm handler in Basta: that's the last thing it prints, to restore the cursor position. The ^[7 toward the end is the start of the next update, to save the cursor position. In between, we expect nothing. Yet, Bash does something: ^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h.  These two escape sequences are private ANSI extensions.  ?2004l is "turn off bracketed paste mode", and ?2004h is "turn off bracketed paste mode". In between is the ^M carriage return that puts the cursor to the start of the line. Bash knows about this because when the user starts typing, some correct cursor movement commands are issued to move to the right spot.
Bottom line, Bash is doing this. But why? Why is Bash fiddling with bracketed paste enabling and disabling terminal escape sequences, just because it received a signal?
The Bash executable is the one from Homebrew, $BASH_VERSION is 5.2.37(1)-release.
More new info: I have confirmed that when Bash has an ALRM trap set and receives that signal, it prints garbage to the terminal. When no trap is set, nothing happens.
The simplest trap we can set which reproduces it is to connect the ALRM signal to the shell null command, which consists of a colon (:):
trap : ALRM

Then if I start a background process which repeatedly sends a SIGALRM to Bash, while Bash sits at the command prompt, Bash repeatedly prints these sequences:
^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M^[[?2004h^[[?2004l^M

If no trap is set for that signal, nothing is printed.  But of course, the trap is just the : command which does nothing; the printing is coming from within Bash somewhere.
It likely has nothing to do with MacOS, except that I've not seen this before, and I'm seeing it on MacOS using the Homebrew build of Bash.

Workaround found, via this answer to a StackOverflow question.
When I put the line
set enable-bracketed-paste 0

into the ~/.inputrc configuration file and start a new Bash session with Basta, I don't see the issue any more.
(While that's great, I still feel that Bash should not be spewing junk to the terminal when it receives a signal that is trapped to a command.)
